# i can't send or receive data using sockets (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, sockets, kotlin

I created a P2p connection by following this  [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct)

after that, I created sockets to send and receive messages but I don't receive or send anything

it supposes to work like that
for each received message it should add it to `messages` which is ArrayList

here is the Client:

```
class ClientMessage(val context: Context,
                    hostAddress: InetAddress,
                    val messages: ArrayList<MessageInfo>
             ) : Thread(){
            lateinit var inputStream : InputStream
            lateinit var outputStream : OutputStream
            private val socket: Socket = Socket()
            var hostAdd: String = hostAddress.hostAddress

    fun writeMessage(message: MessageInfo) {

        val msg = message.message.toByteArray()
        try {
            outputStream.write(msg)
            messages.add(message)
        }
        catch(e: Exception) { }
    }

    override fun run() {
        super.run()

        try {
            socket.connect(InetSocketAddress(hostAdd, 1810), 2000)
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream()
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream()
        }
        catch(e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        val handler = Handler(context.mainLooper)

        executor.execute {
            val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
            var bytes: Int
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer)

                    if (bytes > 0) {
                        val finalBytes = bytes
                        handler.post {
                            val textMessage = String(buffer, 0, finalBytes)
                            val message = MessageInfo("msg", false, 0, textMessage)
                            messages.add(message)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

server:

```
class ServerMessage(val context: Context,
                    val messages: ArrayList<MessageInfo>
                    ) : Thread(){

    lateinit var serverSocket: ServerSocket
    lateinit var inputStream: InputStream
    lateinit var outputStream: OutputStream
    private var socket: Socket = Socket()

    fun writeMessage(message: MessageInfo) {
        val msg = message.message.toByteArray()
        try {
            outputStream.write(msg)
            messages.add(message)
        }
        catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.d("ClientMessage error", e.message.toString())
        }
    }


    override fun run() {
        super.run()

        try{
            serverSocket = ServerSocket(1810)
            socket = serverSocket.accept()
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream()
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream()
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("ClientMessage error", e.message.toString())
        }

        val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        val handler = Handler(context.mainLooper)

        executor.execute {
            val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
            var bytes: Int
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer)

                    if (bytes > 0) {
                        val finalBytes = bytes
                        handler.post {
                            val textMessage = String(buffer, 0, finalBytes)
                            val message = MessageInfo("msg", false, 0, textMessage)
                            messages.add(message)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("ClientMessage error", e.message.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**update**:

Repository:

```
class SocketsRepository(
    private val isHost: Boolean,
    groupOwnerAddress: String?,
    val context: Context,
    ) {
    var messages = arrayListOf<MessageInfo>()




    // host state
    var serverMessage: ServerMessage? = null
    
    // client state
    var clientMessage: ClientMessage? = null
    
    init {

        if (isHost) {
            serverMessage = ServerMessage(context, messages)
            serverMessage!!.start()
        }
        else {

            val address = InetAddress.getByName(groupOwnerAddress)
            clientMessage = ClientMessage(context, address, messages)
            clientMessage!!.start()
        }
    }

    fun sendMessage(message: MessageInfo) {
        if (isHost) {
            sendMessageAsServer(message)
        }
        else {
            sendMessageAsClient(message)
        }
    }

    private fun sendMessageAsClient(message: MessageInfo) {
        if(clientMessage != null) {
            clientMessage!!.writeMessage(message)
        }
    }

    private fun sendMessageAsServer(message: MessageInfo) {
        if(serverMessage != null) {
            serverMessage!!.writeMessage(message)
        }
    }

    fun updateMessages() {
        messages = if (isHost) {
            serverMessage?.messages!!
        } else {
            clientMessage?.messages!!
        }
    }


}
```

ViewModel:

```
class SocketsViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    /**
     * 1- initialize sockets
     *
     * 2- use live data < messages > to update messages
     *
     * 3- use send message or send file to write to connected peer
     * */

    // live data
    private val _messages = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<MessageInfo>>()
    val messages : LiveData<ArrayList<MessageInfo>> = _messages

    // is host sate
    var isHost by Delegates.notNull<Boolean>()
    var groupOwnerAddress: String? = null

    lateinit var socketsRepo: SocketsRepository
    private lateinit var messagesUpdater : Job

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    var context: Context = application.applicationContext

    fun initializeSockets(isHost: Boolean, groupOwnerAddress: String?) {
        this.isHost = isHost
        this.groupOwnerAddress = groupOwnerAddress
        socketsRepo = SocketsRepository(isHost, groupOwnerAddress,context)

        messagesUpdater = GlobalScope.launch{
                while (true) {
                    val newReceivedMessages = socketsRepo.messages
                    _messages.postValue(newReceivedMessages)
                    delay(500)
                }
            }
        startUpdateMessages()
    }

    private fun startUpdateMessages() {
        messagesUpdater.start()
    }

    fun stopUpdateMessages() {
        messagesUpdater.cancel()
    }

    fun sendMessage(message: MessageInfo) {
        socketsRepo.sendMessage(message)
        _messages.value?.add(message)
    }

}
```

Fragment:

```
class ChatFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    var messages = arrayListOf<MessageInfo>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false)
        val socketsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SocketsViewModel::class.java)
        val adapter = ChatAdapter(messages)
        val etWriteMessage: EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.etWriteMessage)
        val btnSendMessage: ImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSendMessage)
        val btnSendFile: ImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSendFile)
        val rvChat: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvChat)

        if(activity != null && isAdded){
            /* ----- Initialize RecyclerView Adapter ----- */
            rvChat.adapter = adapter

            socketsViewModel.messages.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
                if (it != messages) {
                    messages = it
                    adapter.refreshBlockOverlay(messages.size - 1)
                }
            })

            btnSendMessage.setOnClickListener {
                if(etWriteMessage.text.toString() == "") {
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "can't send empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                else {
                    val textMessage = etWriteMessage.text.toString()
                    val message = messageInfoMaker(textMessage)
                    messages.add(message)
                    adapter.refreshBlockOverlay((messages.size - 1))
                    socketsViewModel.sendMessage(message)
                    etWriteMessage.setText("")
                }
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    private fun messageInfoMaker(message: String): MessageInfo {
        return MessageInfo("msg", true, 0, message)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment ChatFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            ChatFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

the app doesn't crash so what is the problem?

Comment: But... You should start telling us if the client can connect to the server.

Comment: For the rest it is quite clear. Both client and server try to read from the input stream. And nobody is writing to the outputstream. Well not that we can see that you send anything.

Comment: there is ```writeMessage``` which write to outputstream

Comment: I'll test if client connecting to server or not

Comment: Yes. But when is writeMessage called? And how? It should be done from a thread also. Not that we can see that you call it.

Comment: see update it called in viewmodel

Comment: And when is sendMessageAsClient called? And the other one? You are not showing how and when. And.. first the sender should send before the receiver can read and you start to read right away at both sides. Further the sending should be done in a thread too and you are probably not doing so. Now is there a connection to begin with?

Comment: I agree with @blackapps - you should start by adding some logging here and there, for example near `outputStream.write(msg)` to verify if you actually invoke this line. Also, you should not assume that received data will be chunked in the same way as sent one. You can send two messages: "A" and "BC", but receive: "AB", "C" on the other side. It seems strange to me that you put both sent and received messages to the same `messages` list, but maybe this is only for debugging.

Comment: I add all of (repository, viewModel, fragment)

Comment: and if you notice I message is an array of MessageInfo which is a data class contain boolean so the application can know if it's sent or received and sorry for late respond

Comment: and about to execute it in a tread is it ok if I used coroutines?

Comment: Still, you don't call `SocketsViewModel.sendMessage()` anywhere in this code. But I'm not sure if it makes sense to share more and more code - just add some logs and see for yourself if you invoke sending or not. It doesn't matter if you use threads or coroutines. The real question is if you call `sendMessage()` concurrently - from two coroutines/threads at the same time.

Comment: take a look at ``` btnSend.setOnClickListener```

Comment: do you mean execute sendMessage in coroutines? if that what do you mean I think it's better to bein executed in the socket class?

Comment: Ahh, I don't know why I missed this. In that case it seems you send messages from UI thread, so you should not have problems with concurrency, but... you will have other problems, because you should not write to socket from UI thread. It will either throw an exception or freeze your app. Actually, I just noticed this line in `ClientMessage.writeMessage()`: `catch(e: Exception) { }` - you silently ignore any exceptions during writing. If you get an exception because of using UI thread, you just ignore it. You log the error in `ServerMessage`.

Comment: ok got it I will use the log to track the problem

Comment: Yeah, logging and debugger are always your best friends when something does not work ;-)